# Memory access time analytical modelling

Tags: caching, memory, memory-management, cpu-architecture

There is this question regarding solving the AMAT(Average Memory Access Time) given these data:

> Legends: Cache Level 1 = L1 Cache Level 2 = L2 Main Memory = M

```
L1, L2 and M's Hit Time are  1, 10 and 100 respectively whilst
L1 Miss Rate is 5%, L2 5% and M 50%.
```

Find the AMAT in clock cycles.

After attempting to solve this question, here is my solution:

```
AMAT's formula is = Hit Time X Hit Rate + Miss Penalty * Miss Rate
Miss Penalty = AMAT for the next cache(say for example, AMAT of L2)
```

So I manipulated the formula, resulting into something like this:

```
AMAT = Hit Time L1 X Hit Rate L1 + AMAT L2 * Miss Rate L1
AMAT L2 = Hit Time L2 X Hit Rate L2 + AMAT M * Miss Rate L2
AMAT M = Hit Time M X Hit Rate M + [???] * Miss Rate M
```

providing the numerical value for the said formula would look like this:

```
AMAT = 1 X .95 + AMAT L2 * .05
AMAT L2 = 10 X .95 + AMAT M * .05
AMAT M = 100 X .5 + [???] * .5
```

So my first question would be, is my formula correct?
Next, how to get M's Miss Penalty?

Answer (score 0):

Your "cascading" deductions are correct. If you miss L1 then the data has to be fetched from L2, involving a penalty, and if you miss L2 the data has to be fetched from RAM involving a higher penalty. Based on this your method of computing AMAT is correct.

Now, let's look a bit at the computer architecture. After L1 you have L2, after L2 there can be an L3 or it can be a RAM. After RAM you have the persistent storage (Hard disk).

However, the access time towards the HDD is very difficult to compute. Majority of the profilers (e.g perf, oprofile) just give you miss rates for the cache and assume that the rest of reads are taken directly from the RAM. Usually this is the case in modern computers. Reads from hard drives are marked as I/O requests. *Why is it hard to compute the HDD access time?* Because your data block can be at any location on your HDD, depending fragmentation. In case of spinning disks the access time can be lower f the data is located near the magnetic reader. So usually HDD access time is hard to predict when computing AMAT.

This means that if the problem statement gives you only L1, L2, M hit time, you cannot compute HDD hit time. However **you can measure/estimate it in real life applications**, using profilers.

So in short:

1. Is your formula correct? **Yes - From mathematical point of view.** From practical point of view, it is hard to use and generally does not make sense if M hit rate is not 100%.
2. How to compute M miss penalty? **If it is not given you cannot compute it.** In practice, by analyzing profiler output you can determine it for a specific measurement (no guaranteed that it will be the same for another measurement, because of the reasons described above).

Cheers.